# NODEJS + EXPRESS - Al usar REQUIRE siempre obtengo "undefined"

Tags: nodejs, api, express, rest

lo primero gracias por molestarte en entrar en la pregunta.

Estoy creando un pequeño backend server para una app web, este backend crea un Api REST que se nutre de otras APIs y a su vez guarda los datos en una bbdd por si se caen las APIs externas.

La estructura de carpetas de mi proyecto que incumbe a mi duda es la siguiente:

```
**ESTRUCTURA CARPETAS**
└───routes
    ├───pre
    └───pro
____index.js
```

En el Index creo un servidor Express cuyo codigo es el siguiente:

```
**INDEX JS**
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

//Crear servidor express
const app = express();

//Configurar cors
app.use(cors());

//Rutas
app.use('/pre/apis', require('./routes/pre/apis'));


//Puerto
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor corriendo en puerto ${ process.env.PORT }`)
});
```

Como podéis ver en una de las rutas llamo al archivo apis (en carpeta routes/pre) a través de un require el cual es el siguiente:

```
**ARCHIVO APIS JS --> Routes/pre/apis.js**
const axios = require('axios');
const { Router } = require('express');

const { getToken } = require('./getToken');

const router = Router();

const token = getToken;
console.log(token);

module.exports = router;
```

Y a su vez aquí llamo a un archivo que sirve para generar un token (getToken) de acceso a la respectiva API externa, este archivo tambien se encuentra en la misma carpeta (routes/pre)

```
**ARCHIVO GETTOKEN JS --> routes/pre/getToken.js**
const axios = require('axios');

const getToken = async() => {

    let token;

    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: ''
    });

    await instance.post()
        .then(r => {
            token = r.data.access_token
            return token;
        }, e => {
            return e;
        });

}

module.exports = getToken;
```

Bien llegados a este punto es cuando viendo mi error comienzan mis dudas sobre como funcionan los requires.

Si ejecuto el archivo getToken directamente SI me genera un token y me lo imprime en consola, sin embargo si ejecuto indexjs automaticamente me responde con un "undefined" que proviene del console.log() que realizo en el archivo apis.

**EJECUTO GETTOKEN**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EJECUTO INDEX**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Sabéis cuál puede ser la solución?

Si has llegado hasta aquí, muchas gracias =)

Comment: Tu problema es (siempre lo es) el manejo de la asincronía. Cuando usas procesos asíncronos (como la generación del *token*) y tratas de usarlo como si fuese síncrono (la sentencia `return` fuera del método `then()`) el resultado siempre será `undefined`. Debes adaptar tu código para que trabaje de forma asíncrona. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, tienes toda la razón, siempre es mi problema (la asincronía es como un dementor que me chupa el alma). He añadido el return dentro del .then como me indicas, y he añadido un await antes del instance.post:

    await instance.post()
        .then(r => {
            token = r.data.access_token
            return token;
        }, e => {
            return e;
        });
Seguimos en las mismas =(

Comment: Lo sé, a lo que me refiero yo es a que la sentencia `return` devuelve inmediatamente un `undefined`, sin esperar a que lo que se ejecuta en el `then()` finalice. En cuanto pueda te preparo una respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto Mauricio, muchas gracias, cuando puedas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema que tienes es el manejo de los procesos asíncronos en tu código. Nada de eso tiene que ver con la forma en que trabaja el método [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/).

Actualmente, en tu código del módulo `getToken.js`, tienes una llamada a un proceso asíncrono:

```
await instance.post()
```

Y aunque la función `getToken` la declaras con la sentencia `async`, no estás tratando el resultado de dicha función como lo que es: una Promesa.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución pasa primero por entender el proceso asíncrono del método de instancia [`post()`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config-1) de [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios), el cual [devuelve](https://github.com/axios/axios#promises) una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).

Una Promesa en esencia lo que su palabra significa: *la promesa de obtener un resultado a futuro*. Y es debido a esta naturaleza (y a la naturaleza del lenguaje [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)) que nunca podremos garantizar cuándo un resultado devuelto por una Promesa esté disponible para ser usado (en una secuencia lineal o síncrona) en nuestro programa.

Hemos de tomar en cuenta que toda función tipo [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) devuelve una Promesa (realmente devuelve una instancia de una [`AsyncFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction)).

Por otro lado, al método `then()` le estás pasando una segunda función, cosa que no es correcto, ya que `then` sólo espera 1 función `callback`. Lo que haces con la segunda función deberías pasarlo al método `catch()`:

```js
let token = await instancia.post()
            .then(callback_1)
            .catch(callback_2);
```

Para entender el funcionamiento de un método asíncrono, veamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
const saludar = async someone => {
  if(!someone) {
    someone = '';
  }
  return `¡Hola ${someone}!`
}

const miSaludo = async () => {
  saludo = await saludar('Mauricio').then(resultado => {
    console.log(`Obtuve este resultado: ${resultado}`);
  });
  console.log(`miSaludo(): ${saludo}`);
}

const miSaludoReturn = async () => {
  saludo = await saludar('MANZARBEITIA').then(resultado => {
    return resultado;
  });
  console.log(`miSaludoReturn(): ${saludo}`);
}

const miSaludoSinThen = async () => {
  saludo = await saludar();
  console.log(`miSaludoSinThen: ${saludo}`);
}


miSaludo();

miSaludoReturn();

miSaludoSinThen();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En el código anterior se tienen 3 casos de llamadas a funciones asíncronas.

En el primer caso, se hace una llamada a la función `saludar` usando la sentencia `await`, y el resultado se asigna a la variable `saludo`. Además, se utiliza el método `then()`, sin embargo dentro del mismo no se devuelve el resultado, solo se muestra por consola. Podemos observar que el resultado asignado a la variable `saludo` es `undefined`.

En el segundo caso, se hace la misma rutina que en el primer caso, pero introducimos una sentencia `return` dentro del método `then`, por lo cual, se devuelve una Promesa. Ya que hemos usado una sentencia `await`, el resultado de esta Promesa (la variable `result` pasada como argumento al `callback` en `then`) se asigna a la variable `saludo`.

En el tercer caso, no usamos el método `then`. Simplemente se recibe el resultado de la función `saludar` en la variable `saludo`. De esta forma el código es incluso más legible, y sería la forma preferida de usar resultados de una Promesa directamente, a menos que queramos manipular el mismo antes de asignarlo a la variable donde será recibido.

Aclarados estos puntos, podemos ajustar tu función `getToken` para que la misma utilice correctamente `then` y `catch`. Además, ajustaremos el código de tu aplicación para que puedas usar correctamente el valor devuelto por esta función.

```js
// ARCHIVO GETTOKEN JS --> routes/pre/getToken.js
const axios = require('axios');

// función tipo async: devuelve una Promesa
const getToken = async() => {
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://auth.es-pre.baikalplatform.com/token?client_id=baikal-api-read&client_secret=B6Dk9CBsfouihKIo8WNh&grant_type=client_credentials'
  });

  let token = await instance.post()
    .then(r => {
      return r.data.access_token;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // debemos decidir qué hacer con el posible error, lo usual es hacer un throw
      throw e;
    });
  // ahora podemos devolver el token
  return token;
}

// ahora podemos exportar nuestra función (recordar que es una Promesa)
module.exports = getToken;
```

Ahora que ya sabemos que nuestro módulo `getToken` devuelve una Promesa, debemos usarlo como tal al momento de hacer el `require`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// ARCHIVO APIS JS --> Routes/pre/apis.js**
const axios = require('axios');
const { Router } = require('express');

// getToken devuelve una Promesa, recordar eso.
const { getToken } = require('./getToken');

const router = Router();

// getToken es una Promesa, para usar su resultado debo usar then y catch
getToken
.then(token => {
  console.log(token);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(`Ocurrió un error al obtener el token: ${error.message}`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

De esta forma al momento de hacer el `require` de nuestro módulo `apis.js` se ejecutará la llamada al método `getToken` y una vez obtenido el resultado se mostrará en pantalla. Si la llamada de `axios` arrojara algún error, el mismo será capturado por el método `catch()` de nuestro módulo `getToken` y como en el mismo estamos simplemente lanzando dicho error, el mismo será capturado por nuestro método `catch` en `apis.js` donde nos mostrará el mensaje de error.

Para usar el valor del `token` siempre debemos recordar que el mismo es el resultado de un proceso asíncrono (el método `post` de `axios` es asíncrono), por lo cual, la única forma de tener acceso a dicho resultado será dentro de una función `callback` pasada como argumento al método `then` o usando la sentencia `await` (dentro de una función o entorno `async`) para esperar directamente por dicho resultado.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema y aclare un poco más el uso de procesos asíncronos.

Answer (score 2):

El problema como comentan es que no estas esperando; donde sea que lo estas requiriendo, al resolve de la funcion, pues cuando haces que una función sea asincrona la conviertes en una promesa automaticamente.

La solución al problema es simple, utilizar `then` para obtener el retorno, pero esto lo convierte en un problema de callbacks (o no), asi que si estas utilizando express puedes siempre puesdes convertir en asincrona el callback de la request:

```
router.get('/apiKey', async (req, res) => await getToken)
```

La otra solución que es la mejor, es utilizar las ultimas versiones de node que admiten soporte para *Top-level await* como lo dice en este [changelog de v8](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await)

Haciendolo tan sencillo como en Deno:

```
// Top-level scope
let apikey = await getToken
```

Anteriormente esto no hubiese funcionado y tendrias que haber hecho algo como

```
// Top-level scope
(async function() {
  let apikey = await getToken;
}());
```

**EDIT**:

Igualmente me doy cuenta de que no estas retornando la función como deberias, para esto solo cambia un par de lineas:

```
const getToken = async () => {

  let token;

  const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://auth.es-pre.baikalplatform.com/token?client_id=baikal-api-read&client_secret=B6Dk9CBsfouihKIo8WNh&grant_type=client_credentials'
  });

  let res = await instance.post();
  let { data } = res:
  return data.access_token

}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.